# At what point are file-local and dir-local variables applied to a newly-loaded buffer?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, company-mode, directory-local-variables, file-local-variables

I'm currently attempting to call the function [`company-org-roam--init-hook`](https://github.com/jethrokuan/company-org-roam/blob/0913d86f167164e18831206e611f44bb8e7297e3/company-org-roam.el#L141) from `org-mode-hook` in order to enable the `company-org-roam` backend in `org-roam` buffers. In some of the files in which this hook is called, I've used a `.dir-locals.el` file to set `org-roam-directory` to a non-default value. However, when `company-org-roam--init-hook` is called while loading the file, it appears that `org-roam-directory` isn't set to its dir-local value, causing the hook not to enable the Company backend.

Is it expected that dir-local variables are applied only after major-mode hooks are run? If so, is there a way to work around this (besides a `run-at-time`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it expected that dir-local variables are applied only after major-mode hooks are run?

Yes.  The local variables are *normally* processed in `run-mode-hooks`, after running the mode hooks and before running `after-change-major-mode-hook`.

You could use the latter to deal with your problem.  Alternatively you can use `hack-local-variables-hook` which runs after the local variables have been processed -- refer to [How can I access directory-local variables in my major mode hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5147060/324105)

n.b. How and when file- and dir-local variables are processed changed in Emacs 26.1, and the linked S.O. Q&A pre-dates that change.  I don't believe it affects your question, but the implementation details were different.

Comment: In retrospect, the `after-change-major-mode-hook` approach wouldn't work in old Emacs versions; that hook is only an option (for the purposes of this question) from 26.1 onwards.  Using `hack-local-variables-hook` will work for all versions.